# Modeling a list with a tunable degree of disorder/shuffling

Tags: ranking, entropy, kullback-leibler, randomness

Imagine we have a list of ordered numbers $L = (1, 2,\dots, N)$.

I want to add an arbitrary amount of "disorder" to that list.  For instance:

- Adding a little bit of disorder would permute a few neighboring numbers
- Adding more disorder would permute several numbers, many of them not neighbors
- Adding maximal disorder would permute all the numbers

Ideally I would like to use an algorithm that has a sound statistical/information theoretic foundation.

I am not sure about how to search for this.  I have tried Googling things like:

- Tunable degree of shuffling
- Generating random lists of numbers with a given entropy / Kullback-Leibler distance
- Generating a list with a given level of presortedness

Note that the solution is not just shuffling a given percentage of the numbers.  When disorder is small, the shuffling should occur among numbers that are close.

Comment: It's an interesting question (+1).  You could guide the answers by supplying some information about your intended application, because often the context reveals much about how to model the random variation in the data.

Comment: I am imagining something like I have a number of casino tokens ordered one after the other on top of a one dimensional table.  Then I shake the table along its dimension and see in what order the tokens landed.  The tunable degree of disorder I want to model corresponds to how much I shake the table.

Comment: Is this "shaking" an example of your actual application (or at least a good physical model of it)?

Comment: Yes, it is a good physical model.

Comment: I would start with looking into Persi Diaconis' "Group representation theory in probability and statistics"  for probability models on permutations.

Comment: Hmm... I seem to remember answering this question before. There is a duplicate here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/94246/modeling-a-list-with-a-tunable-degree-of-disorder-shuffling